# How do I mention a member in a text? Discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, userid

```
if message.content.startswith('!givecookie @member'):
   await message.channel.send('Hello, @member, here is your cookie~ :cookie:')
```

So how can I add a member(@member) to the command when mentioning someone? What the command is supposed to do is - give cookie to a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn’t be using
`if message.content.startswith(“!givecookie @member")` 
It would be better to declare client using
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!”)`.
After that you can use

```
@client.command()
async def givecookie(ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter):
  await ctx.send(f"Hello, {member.mention}, here is your cookie~ :cookie:")
```

This means that your bot now has the prefix “!”, and using `@client.command` can make more commands that you can use in discord. The parameters passed in this command (ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter) mean the context and the specific member you want to give the cookie to respectively. `ctx.send(f“Hello, {member.mention}, here is your cookie~ :cookie:")` will basically send the message but it will also ping the member. Telling the bot to send “@member” will make it literally send "@member”. Also, the command will only work when you start a message with “!givecookie @member”, but not if you do “!give cookie {pinging that specific member}”.

In conclusion, you should use client.command() to use commands instead of checking the message’s content.

API Reference

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Prefixes:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#prefix-helpers

Commands:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#commands

Comment: It should work, but now it's showing me an error in ```commands.Bot(command_prefix="!”)``` and ```commands.MemberConverter``` saying 'name "commands" is not defined'. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you also have to also import commands using `from discord.ext import commands` at the top of your python file.